# Contains method in 2D collection

Tags: c#, arraylist

How to compare auto[0] in cars array by "Name" field?
The string `if (!cars.Contains(auto[0]))` is incorrect ofcourse.

```
namespace AutoSqare
{
    class CarsInfo
    {
        static List<Tech> cars = new List<Tech>();
        public class Tech
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double KM { get; set; }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] auto = new string[]{"Lada Vesta"};
            cars.Add(new Tech()
            {
                    Name = "Lada Vesta Sport",
                    KM = 190
            });

            if (!cars.Contains(auto[0]))
            cars.Add(new Tech()
            {
                    Name = auto[0],
                    KM = 0
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try implementing the Equals method, which takes a string as an argument and returns a bool. You might need to inherit from the IComparable interface in your Tech class, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (!cars.Any(car => car.Name.Equals(auto[0])))
            cars.Add(new Tech()
            {
                Name = auto[0],
                KM = 0
            });
```

[Any](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) will return true, if there is an element within the collection that satisfies the condition, the Condition being `car.Name.Equals(auto[0])`. Thats why you can use `!cars.Any(car => car.Name.Equals(auto[0]))` to see if theres no car within your collection where the predicate applies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ's `Any()` method:

```
if (!cars.Any(c => c.Name == auto[0]))
```

But it seems that you plan to have only *unique* car names, so using a `Dictionary<string,Tech>` seems better than a `List<Tech>`:

```
static Dictionary<string, Tech> cars = new Dictionary<string,Tech>();

static void Main()
{
    string[] auto = new string[]{"Lada Vesta"}; // <-- you also had a syntax error here
    Tech tech = new Tech()
        {
            Name = "Lada Vesta Sport",
            KM = 190
        };
    cars.Add(tech.Name, tech);        

    if (!cars.ContainsKey(auto[0]))  // <--- Use ContainsKey here
        cars.Add(auto[0], new Tech()
            {
                Name = auto[0],
                KM = 0
            });
}
```

Comment: Should I use `public class Tech
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public double KM { get; set; }
        }` with your code?

Comment: @SharpUser yes of course, I just cut it out for brevity

Comment: @SharpUser than you mixed both answers: My dictionary uses `ContainsKey`, but you probably still try to use `Any()` on the dictionary, which won't work and is inferior to `ContainsKey`.